# How to set up a background image for a JPanel?

Tags: jpanel

I'm trying to set up a background image for a JPanel but when I do it, it covers the buttons I have on the JPanel. How can I make it so that the buttons stay on TOP of the background and not being covered by it?

Answer (score 0):

Paint the background, and just add your components to the panel.

```
class SomePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public SomePanel() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
        add(new JButton("Hello"));
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }
}
```

Or just use a label with an icon, set the layout manager for the label, and add all your components to the label.

Comment: I've seen this so many times, but I don't know how to change `image` for the actual image file. What type does it need to be? Image? ImageIcon?

Comment: It should be an `Image` to paint. I always use a `BufferedImage` which is a `Image` type. Se updated code. If you're already using an `ImageIcon`, just use `ImageIcon.getImage()` to return an `Image`

Comment: When I try it, it crashes here `image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/image.png"));`. It says input == null!
I'm calling it from the main like this:
SomePanel label2 = new SomePanel();

Comment: Well if your using my exact code, then you need to have a package named `resources` in the `src` and have an actual image file named `image.png` inside the `resources` ;-)

Comment: I had it outside the src folder! Thanks! One last question, do you know how can I make a button be the same size as the button icon?

Comment: You should another question, as it's unrelated. Also if you do post another question, I suggest you post some code (attempt).